# Can I put pizza dough in the fridge after 12 hours of rising

Tags: pizza, neapolitan-pizza

I’m making pizza dough with the original intention of letting the dough rise for about 20 hours (the recipe I’m using calls for a 8-22 hour rise period before making the pizza). However, I’ve had a change of plans and won’t be able to have the pizza tonight. Can I put the dough in the fridge for the next day? I’ll bring to room temperature before making the pizza when I do use it

Comment: I don't see an issue with it, my wife will sometimes make dough and freeze it to make pizza later through the week.  And when she does make it (from the dough that was in the freezer) it still tastes amazing, especially on the pizza stone.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, pizza dough can be moved to the refrigerator after an initial rise, even after 24 or more hours at room temperature.  [See also this question.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/111010/should-i-reshape-refrigerated-pizza-dough-into-ball-again-when-taking-it-out-of?rq=1)

Answer (score 7):

From my own experience it tends to become a bit slimey if left rising too long (72 hours unrefrigerated), but the fridge cuts the effect of letting it rise further massively (I'd say roughly 1/4).

You're not destroying the yeast (that's doing the rising), you're only massively slowing it's metabolism, so in effect you're merely changing the speed at which it rises.

8 degree celsius (or whatever your fridge is running) should definitely buy you another day if you're "only" 12 hours in.

Comment: Dough should be retarded between 1.7 and 4.4 C (35 - 40 F). Warmer than that will allow the yeast to continue break down the proteins, which might be why your dough becomes slimey. Source: https://www.bakingbusiness.com/articles/39656-pyler-says-understanding-proofing-and-retarding

Comment: @hodale the slimy remark was about dough that I didn't even try to refrigerate, but thanks for providing actual numbers when fridges just slow vs actually stop the yeasts progress

Comment: Oh, I see, I misread that!